# fs.rmSync throws undefined is not a function on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

I am trying to delete a simple folder with another folder inside of it, like: `/tmp/ac6c1fcaeae0c7ec4d1a8/res`.

To do so I have this simple code:

```
module.exports.deleteFolder = (path) => {
    try {
        if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
            console.log("Deleting folder " + path)
            fs.rmSync(path, { recursive: true })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error deleting folder at " + path)
        throw error
    }
}
```

When I run this on Windows with Node 16.13.2 it works, and I am deploying using `pkg` to an Ubuntu machine, that had Node 10.x but I upgraded it using `nvm` (although I think it shouldn't matter because the machine that I am using for compiling is also on 16.13.2 although it was on 12.x and I upgraded it using `nvm` as well).

Maybe the machine where I am compiling is not using the `nvm` node version? Because I read that this function was added on 14.x.

To sum up, I am using Windows for developing, an Ubuntu WSL that had node 12.x for compiling (and I upgraded to 16.13.2 using `nvm`) and another Ubuntu machine where I will deploy. It is working on Windows but not on the production machine.

EDIT: compiling it with the Windows machine failed too, looks like that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like I was using an outdated version of `pkg`, and since it was taking the global option, it was using node14 as target.

Changed the `pkg-config` file to node16, then I could see the error. Updated all global npm packages, recompiled and it worked!